# K-nearest neighbors for a moving query point

Tags: algorithm, indexing, machine-learning, knn

I have been given coordinates of n fixed points and m query points. I have to find the k-nearest neighbors of each of the m query points from the n fixed points. Finding distances separately for each query point is very costly. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: the dimensionalality of the data matters a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are fast indexing structures for such problems, like **[KD Tree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#kd-tree)** or **[Ball Tree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#ball-tree)**. In particular - scikit-learn (sklearn) implements them in their knn routines ( http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html )

Answer (score 1):

A real answer to your question depends on numerous factors. For example, if you are not using the Euclidean distance - then you can't use KDTrees. There is also scaling issues (how many points enrolled? Dimension Size? "Clustered" ness) How long you can wait for training, if values need to be added to the set, and so on.

A number of less commonly available, bust still useful, algorithms for such are available in [JSAT](https://code.google.com/p/java-statistical-analysis-tool/). This includes [VP Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantage-point_tree), [RBC](http://www.lcayton.com/rbc.pdf), and [LSH](http://www.mit.edu/~andoni/LSH/). (bias warning, I'm the author of JSAT)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working out the square root of the sum of the squares to get the distances, try dropping the square root which is computationally intensive. Just find the ones with the nearest squared distances - they are the same points.

Comment: Why is this marked down please? It is a perfectly legitimate answer to the question.

Comment: I agree -- would the downvoter please elaborate his objection to this answer